# How do you include in a Azure Function 3.1 files referenced from another project

Tags: azure-functions

I have multiple projects references by my Azure Function project. When running locally the folder/file (Files/paid_watermark.png) is included in the bin folder. When deployed the Folder/File no longer exists. How can I include it in the deployed folder so I am able to still reference it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds that worked for us was to first publish it to our function project's local folder or file sharing.

[image]

Then, from the bin folder, we can see the folders and files within our function project.

[image]

Then try publishing again we can find the folders/files from site -> wwwroot -> Files -> Sample.jpeg

[image]